# Navigating from an UserControl and passing a complex object

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, navigation, windows-phone-8

I'm struggling to understand how navigation works on WP8 and I'm facing this problem:

let's assume that I have a custom control in a separate project, and I've got a control settings page in the same project.

So here's the structure:

```
CustomControlProject
                    |- CustomControl.xaml
                    |- CustomControlSettings.xaml
```

CustomControl extends `UserControl`.

Now, what I want to do is to pass some data to `CustomControlSettings.xaml` and I'm talking about a complex object (a `StackPanel`).

Since `CustomControl` is a `UserControl`, I've got no `NavigationService` so I'm using this code (I found it here on stackoverflow but I've lost the tab):

```
    /// <summary>

    /// Walk visual tree to find the first DependencyObject  of the specific type.

    /// </summary>

    private DependencyObject GetDependencyObjectFromVisualTree(DependencyObject startObject, Type type)
    {

        //Walk the visual tree to get the parent(ItemsControl)

        //of this control

        DependencyObject parent = startObject;

        while (parent != null)
        {

            if (type.IsInstanceOfType(parent))

                break;

            else

                parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);

        }

        return parent;

    }
```

so that I can do

```
Page pg = GetDependencyObjectFromVisualTree(this, typeof(Page)) as Page;
pg.NavigationService ...
```

Passing a complex object requires something else so I followed the instructions here: http://www.sharpregion.com/easy-windows-phone-7-navigation/

This ends up in having a navigation method like this one:

```
base.OnTap(e);
Page pg = GetDependencyObjectFromVisualTree(this, typeof(Page)) as Page;
NavigationExt.Navigator.Navigate<DestinationPage>(pg.NavigationService, objectToPass);
```

What happens is that I'm using this control in another project, as a child of `MainPage.xaml`.

This should mean that `Page pg = GetDependencyObjectFromVisualTree(this, typeof(Page)) as Page;` will get the `MainPage` as `pg` and this lead to an exception because there's no `DestinationPage.xaml` in the same folder as the `MainPage.xaml`.

```
    Message "No XAML was found at the location '/DestinationPage.xaml'."
```

So the question is:

if I have a custom control and a page in project B, how can I pass an object to the page and navigate to it if I reference project B from a project A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your question and your code, I understand that you want to navigate to a page when some element is tapped in your user control. Both the page and the user control are located in a different project than your main project.

Since your user control is going to be hosted in some page in your main project, the URI when navigating should be as follows:

```
/{assemblyName};component/{relativePath}
```

Now, `NavigationService` isn't available from within `UserControl` but you can use `Application.RootVisual`

```cs
base.OnTap(e);
var frame = Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
frame.Navigate(new Uri("/CustomControlProject;component/CustomControlSettings.xaml",
       UriKind.Relative));
```

For passing objects to pages, there are quite a few approaches. One of them is taking advantage of `PhoneApplicationService`.

You could do something like this:

```cs
base.OnTap(e);
MyObjectType objectToPass = new MyObjectType();
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["myObject"] = objectToPass;
var frame = Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
frame .Navigate(new Uri("/CustomControlProject;component/CustomControlSettings.xaml",
    UriKind.Relative));

// In destination page's constructor
public CustomControlSettings() {
  var myObject = (MyObjectType) PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["myObject"];
  // ...
}
```